# How to create a postscript file using print to file option in word with C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, postscript

I want to create a postscript file from a word document(.doc) using print to file from Microsoft word and C#, I found lots of ways to print a file but couldn't find "Print to file".

Answer (score 4):

Unless things have changed, you don't 'print to file' you 'print to a printer on FILE:'

So what you need to do is create a printer instance using the driver of your choice, and have it send its data to the FILE: hardware (rather than LPT!: COM!: USB001: etc).

On Windows versions up to 7 (I have no information yet on Windows 8) it is possible to create a Port Monitor and install that, this can then write the data to file instead. You still have to create a printer instance which uses that Port Monitor though.

Comment: Hi There, Thanks for your answer.I write this code but the problem is that it still send the file to printer instead of "printing to a file".

Comment: Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
wordApp.Visible = false;
PrintDialog pDialog = new PrintDialog();
pDialog.AllowPrintToFile = true;
pDialog.PrintToFile = true;
pDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "\\\\cmrsyds02\\BlackBox288";
pDialog.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
pDialog.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = @"c:\Holding.ps";
Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Add(@"c:\Holding.doc");
wordApp.ActivePrinter = pDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
doc.PrintOut();
doc.Close(SaveChanges: false);
doc = null;
wordApp.Quit(SaveChanges: false);
wordApp = null;

Comment: You can't 'print to a file' without sending data to a printer, because the conversion form GDI (or XPS on recent versions of WIndows) to the printer's page description language is done by the printer driver. Obviously you can't invoke the printer driver (and this conversion) without sending to a printer. I have to admit I'm not at all clear on what your problem actually is... THe code supplied looks like it opens a print dialog box, allows the print to file checkbox and checks it (in this case it doesn't matter what port you are using). So what is actually wrong ?

Comment: I want to convert a doc to ps, this code didn't work I don't want the print dialogue to open then I choose print to file to save the file in ps format.I read an article which said I can't do it pragmatically.now I don't know how to convert my file to ps!

Comment: This URL http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/9651-command-line-printing-a-word-document/ about halfway down the first page has a post from 'James' (6th April 2007) which tells you how to print a Word file to a printer.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new printer.

Select - Local printer attached to this printer

Use port - FILE: (print to file)

Choose a postscript printer from the list, such as an Apple LaserWriter 16/600 PS (or an 11x17 printer for larger output or an imagesetter for variable page size ability)

Then just print to the printer